# Read and save unknown key value pair in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

I am making an API call. On successful completion I know the structure of JSON response. I can read that and save it on DB using JSON.NET, but if the API calls generates error, a JSON of unknown structure is generated. I have to parse and save it in DB. How can I do that.

In genral structure of error response is this:

```
{"origin-of_error":"error_message"}
```

There are some cases though where additional key value is also present.

Comment: Has the unknown json-object always the structure origin : error like `{ foo : bar }` or could it be `{ foo : bar, zuu : xaa }` as well?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Yes it is always like {foo:bar} but sometimes additionally it gives {foo: bar, koo:kaa} structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know the exact contents of the JSON, but you at least know it is a flat object with key-value pairs, then I would recommend deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, string>`. You can then easily iterate over the key-value pairs to extract the data you need to store in the DB.

```
string json = @"
{
    ""origin-of_error"" : ""error_message"",
    ""foo"" : ""bar""
}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
IDictionary<string, JToken> jsondata = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> innerData in jsondata) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}=> {1}",innerData.Key, innerData.Value.ToString()); 
            }
```